# Response.Cookies when sessionState mode="InProc"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-config

I am wondering what the below code is doing? When `sessionState` Mode is `"InProc"` or is it correct?
 `Response.Cookies(My.Settings.TESTSessionCookieName).Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)`
Why the previous developer used the above code instead of `Sessioin timeout="20"` to remove session.

*Web.Config*

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieName="TESTSession" timeout="20">
    <setting name="TESTSessionCookieName" serializeAs="String">
        <value>TESTSession</value>
    </setting>
```

*Aspx.page.vb*

```
Session.Abandon()
Response.Cookies(My.Settings.TESTSessionCookieName).Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
Response.Redirect(My.Settings.generalErrorURL)
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The code is expiring their session (abandon and cookie value).  InProc is the default session storage mechanism, all data is stored IN PROCess.  Session Timeout = "20" will not remove their session, it just means the session will last 20 minutes without refresh before expiring.

Comment: thx, so Session.Abandon and Response.Cookies(XXX).expires is a correct way

Comment: `Session.Abandon();` is enough for me, the second line `.Expires` will just ensure the cookie is also removed from the clients browser, and if the session is re-initialized, then the session id will be different.